# When is this equation involving binary strings satisfied?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, binary, binary-operations

Let $k$ be an $n$-bit string denoting a natural number.  Let $1$ denote the $n$-bit string consisting of all $0$’s except a $1$ at the end, and let $2$ denote the $n$-bit string consisting of all $0$’s except for $1$ at the second to last place.  Let $\oplus$ denote bitwise XOR, and let $+$ denote natural number addition.  Then my question is, under what circumstances does $((k\oplus 1) + 1) \oplus 1 = (k+1) \oplus 2$?

This question arose in the context of writing a cryptography proof; my proof hinges on the assumption that a randomly chosen $n$-bit string $k$ has a very small probability of satisfying this equation.

Comment: Just to clarify, natural number addition is just normal addition right?

Comment: @VarunVejalla Yeah

Comment: @VarunVejalla Well. $k\geq 0$ is true.  $k$ can equal $0$.

Comment: If $k \mod 4 \in \{0, 1\}$, then both sides will be equal, so there is a large probability of satisfying the equation. Are you sure you didn't make a typo somewhere?

Comment: @VarunVejalla I may be able to live with that.  If $k \mod 4 \in \{2, 3\}$, is the equation always false?

Comment: Yes, it's always false if $k \mod 4 \in \{2, 3\}$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla OK, can you post an answer showing why it’s always true for $\{0,1\}$ and always false for $\{2,3\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k$ is even, then $k \oplus 1 = k+1$, while if $k$ is odd, $k \oplus 1 = k-1$. This is seen simply by XORing the digit in the $1$s place with $1$.

This means that if $k$ is even, the LHS evaluates to $(k+1+1) \oplus 1 = k+3$.

If $k$ is odd, then the LHS evaluates to $(k-1+1) \oplus 1 = k \oplus 1 = k-1$.

If there is a $0$ in the $2$s place in the binary expansion of $n=k+1$, then $n \oplus 2 = n+2$. If there is a $1$ instead, then $n \oplus 2 = n-2$. Note that there is a $0$ if $n \mod 4 \in \{0, 1\}$, or equivalently if $k \mod 4 \in \{ 3, 0 \}$.

Making a chart based off the mod $4$ value of $k$ yields
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k\mod 4 & ((k\oplus 1) + 1) \oplus 1 & (k+1)\oplus 2\\
 0 & k+3 & k+1+2=k+3\\
 1 & k-1 & k+1-2=k-1\\
 2 & k+3 & k+1-2=k-1\\
 3 & k-1 & k+1+2=k+3
\end{array}
\right)
$$

As you can see, they are only equivalent for $k \mod 4 \in \{0, 1\}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  And FYI, it turns out that a 50-50 chance is good enough for my proof!